# Get files from amazon s3 buckets sub folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get all the files from a amazon S3 buckets sub folder and make them downloadable in a web page.

I have a bucket called images. Inside that bucket I have some other folders. Now I am trying to get all the files inside that subfolder and show it in a page.
    S3 Buckets: 
    /images
    /images/test1/
    /images/test2/
    /images/test1/1
    /images/test1/2
    /images/test1/1/item

I have tried like this, but couldn't get the expected result.

```
// Target files full path : images/test1/1/item 

$bucketName = 'images';
$source = '/test1/1/item' 

$image = $this->s3->getBucket($bucketName);
foreach ($image as $key=>$data){
   $k = $data['name'];
   print_r($k); // now this gives me full list of everything inside the images bucket. 
}
```

Now if I want to get objects from the bucket, I can use getObject, which I tried like this:

```
$result = $this->s3->getObject($image); // I am confused about this one
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks,

After using the following answer from Josue Ibarra, I got something like this

```
(

 [tableuploads/1/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.03.23-emailList.csv] => Array
     (
         [file_name] => 15.10.2013-18.03.23-emailList.csv
         [file_folder] => emaillists
         [file_size] => 64
         [created_on] => 2013-10-15 19:03:26
         [s3_link] => http://s3.amazonaws.com/webtools_sharing/emaillists/15.10.2013-       18.03.23-emailList.csv
        [md5_hash] => 4809ae0b75d3517b69f69b53ba0b2959
    )

[tableuploads/1/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.04.32-emailList.csv] => Array
    (
        [file_name] => 15.10.2013-18.04.32-emailList.csv
        [file_folder] => emaillists
        [file_size] => 64
        [created_on] => 2013-10-15 19:04:45
        [s3_link] => http://s3.amazonaws.com/webtools_sharing/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.04.32-emailList.csv
        [md5_hash] => 14094e133779619ddfcfc008d16ce75b
    )

[tableuploads/2/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.03.23-emailList.csv] => Array
    (
        [file_name] => 15.10.2013-18.03.23-emailList.csv
        [file_folder] => emaillists
        [file_size] => 64
        [created_on] => 2013-10-15 19:03:26
        [s3_link] => http://s3.amazonaws.com/webtools_sharing/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.03.23-emailList.csv
        [md5_hash] => 4809ae0b75d3517b69f69b53ba0b2959
    )

[tableuploads/2/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.04.32-emailList.csv] => Array
    (
        [file_name] => 15.10.2013-18.04.32-emailList.csv
        [file_folder] => emaillists
        [file_size] => 64
        [created_on] => 2013-10-15 19:04:45
        [s3_link] => http://s3.amazonaws.com/webtools_sharing/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.04.32-emailList.csv
        [md5_hash] => 14094e133779619ddfcfc008d16ce75b
    )
)
```

I want something like this:
    http://s3.amazonaws.com/webtools_sharing/tableuploads/1/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.03.23- emailList.csv

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/webtools_sharing/tableuploads/2/emaillists/15.10.2013-18.03.23-emailList.csv
```

Which needs to be a downloadable link.

Please suggest me to a link or give me some ideas how can I do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this function a while back

```
public function list_s3_bucket($bucket_name)
{
    // initialize the data array
    $data;
    $bucket_content = $this->s3->getBucket($bucket_name);

    foreach ($bucket_content as $key => $value) {
        // ignore s3 "folders"
        if (preg_match("/\/$/", $key)) continue;

        // explode the path into an array
        $file_path = explode('/', $key);
        $file_name = end($file_path);
            $file_folder = substr($key, 0, (strlen($file_name) * -1)+1);
        $file_folder = prev($file_path);

        $s3_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/{$bucket_name}/{$key}";

        $data[$key] = array(
            'file_name' => $file_name,
                    's3_key' => $key,
            'file_folder' => $file_folder,
            'file_size' => $value['size'],
            'created_on' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value['time']),
            's3_link' => $s3_url,
            'md5_hash' => $value['hash']);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

It returns you an array, the key is the full file name, so you can do:

```
$list = $this->your_model->list_s3_bucket($bucket_name);

foreach ($list as $key => $row){
   force_download($this->s3->getObject($row['s3_key']), $row['file_name']);
   // you can use this url:
   print($row['s3_link']);
}

function force_download($data, $file_name)
{
      header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file_name}\"");
      echo $data;
}
```

Comment: it also ignores the empty s3 folders you get, it detects them because they have a '/' at the end of their name. **example:** 'folder1/'

Comment: for me until $list = $this->your_model->list_s3_bucket($bucket_name); is working. Inside the foreach loop it's not working in $result = $this->s3->getObject($key); Do I have also tried it like this: $result = $this->s3->getObject($bucketname,$key);

Comment: inside foreach why we have to call getObject again??

Comment: Get object is only called once, inside of the foreach loop it will download the actual file (the filename is stored in the $key of the loop)

Comment: I intended for the code to be clear of the usage, not to be a drop-in replacement. Im sorry for that confusion, the "webtools_sharing" is MY bucket name xD I forgot to take it out of my code

Comment: Please change `$s3_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<yourbucketgoeshere>/{$key}";` to add your bucket name. and don't run the example line `$result = $this->s3->getObject($row['s3_key']);` inside of the foreach loop it will download everything and will show nothing (unless you output the file with the proper headers in each loop)

Comment: Hi thanks, please look at my question again, I have edited it.I used your code and I got the result as above (in my question). Your code is working really fine, one thing I am confused now. What if I have more folders inside the folders. I tried something like this to see what come out. $file_folder = prev($file_path).'/tableuploads/1'; which is not the right way to do it. Please suggest me something.Thanks in advance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39762/discussion-between-bukamanush-and-josue-ibarra)