# PHP get objects in folder from S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket. I have the file I want to look in, let's say it's "/stackoverflow.com/myfile/awesome". It has 10 files inside of it that I want to get the data from (images etc).

I read this: [Get files from amazon s3 buckets sub folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424536/get-files-from-amazon-s3-buckets-sub-folder)

However I don't want to simply get all the files in the bucket. How can I retrieve all of the files using PHP?

My pseudocode would be something like this:

```
bucket = s3.getbucket()

function getNamesOfObjectsInLocation(loc):
  myFile = bucket.getAt(loc)
  keys=[]
  for objects in myFile:
    keys.append(objects.location)
  return keys

function getObjectsByKey(key):
  return bucket.getAt(key)

function doTask()
  keys = getNamesOfObjectsInLocation("/stackoverflow.com/myfile/awesome")
  objects=[]
  for k in keys:
    objects.append(getObjectsByKey(k))

  return objectsI 

results = doTask()
```

I'm using: http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class for my S3 class however I can't figure out how to use it to do the above. Any ideas?

I assume I'd use `.getBucket` but I don't see a way to get all of the inner files / locations... but it may be my inexperience with PHP. I don't see any documentation of bucket in undesigned.org.za, I'm looking through the code now but still unsure. Thanks!

Comment: I think that's a fairly old library, and perhaps not the best choice for broad support, but I'm not a php specialist.  Scrolling down through the page comments on the link you provided, it appears getBucket accepts a prefix, which would be like a "path," and should return only the objects in the pseudo-folder you specify there.  Familiarizing yourself with the low level REST API would be helpful, since then you would know the mechanisms the library would be working with, and terms like "prefix" and "marker" would make sense in context.

Comment: Yes I actually ended up using the aws SDK... Thank you, it meant I had to refactor some things a bit but in the end it worked out, thank you